# Page keep freezing on jQuery load more

Tags: php, jquery

**My page ui keep freezing each time the load more is fire once or multiple times to load more videos and all the videos play button get freeze/hang.
Here is the PHP code**

It unfreeze back only when data has loaded, Any help is appreciated.
I have tried lots of solution by turning async to true but same freezing

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST["limit"], $_REQUEST["start"])){      
$sSQL='SELECT * from posts  WHERE 
    created_at >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL
     -2 DAY
order by uni 
    ';
$result =   $db->getRecFrmQry($sSQL.' LIMIT '.$_REQUEST["start"].', '.$_REQUEST["limit"].' ');}
foreach($result as $val){
        ?>
    


    <div class="section" style="background:black;margin-bottom:-35px">
          
<video style="margin-bottom:-150px"
poster="bgv.png" 
    x5-playsinline="" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" x5-video-player-type="h5" x-webkit-airplay="true">

<source src="/ver/videos/<?php echo $val['video']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

**It unfreeze back only when data has loaded using this jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var limit = 2;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_country_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"listing-data.ajax.php",
   method:"GET",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<center><i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin' style='font-size:35px,color:white'></i></center>");
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }

 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  load_country_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()+100 > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_country_data(limit, start);
   }, 10);
  }
 });
 
});
```

Comment: Perhaps look in the network tab, I could imagine your code looping - you need to debounce and clearTimeout before setTimeout

Comment: @mplungjan  how to clearTimout before setTimeout, any sample code is welcome. Thanks

Comment: `let tId;  $(window).scroll(function(){ .... clearTimeout(tId);  tId = setTimeout(function(){`
Please look up debounce scroll

Comment: @mplungjan Please adjust it to my to my code, still bit new to jQuery.

Comment: I just declared the var before your function and added `clearTimeout(tId);` and `tId=` that is all. It should be recognisable where

Comment: @mplungjan I don't know if am placing it wrong but the page still freezing, a full code is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here is what I have

Comment: $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()+100 > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {clearTimeout(tId);
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   tId=setTimeout(function(){
    load_country_data(limit, start);
   }, 10);
  }

Comment: You need to add `let tId; ` just before `$(window).scroll` - but this could be just one of the changes you need. I cannot eyeball debug your code

Comment: @mplungjan I did but unfortunately the page still freezing

Comment: let tId;
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()+100 > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {clearTimeout(tId);
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   tId=setTimeout(function(){
    load_country_data(limit, start);
   }, 10);
  }
 });

Comment: @mplungjan No it still freezing, all videos, scroll hang, video play button freeze until it process data

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that the interface stops responding while data is rendering.

Here is a version that is easier to debug

Do you get the console message only when you stop scrolling?

How many videos does the server return in one go?

I also recommend you do not return HTML from the server but just enough data to render the HTML on the client (an array of video URLs)

```js
$(function() {
  const limit = 2;
  let start = 0;
  let active = false;
  let tId;
  const template = $("#vidDiv").html();
  const process = arr => {
    if (arr.length === 0) return; // nothing to process
    arr.forEach(vid => {
      const $div = $(template)
      $div.find("source").attr("src", `/ver/videos/${vid}`)
      $('#load_data').append($div);
    });  
  };
  const load_country_data = (limit, start) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: "listing-data.ajax.php",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json", 
      data: {
        limit: limit,
        start: start
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(arr) { // always gets an array
        const active = arr.length === 0;
        $('#load_data_message').html(
          active ? "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>" : "<center><i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin' style='font-size:35px,color:white'></i></center>"
        );  
        process(arr);
      }
    });
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (active) return;
    const height = $("#load_data").height();
    const topHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 100;
    if (topHeight <= height) return;
    active = true;
    start += limit;
    clearTimeout(tId);
    tId = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("New load",start); // this should only happen when you stop scrolling
      load_country_data(limit, start);
    }, 10);
  });
  load_country_data(limit, start);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="load_data_message"></span>
<div id="load-data"></div>

<template id="vidDiv">
  <div class="section" style="background:black;margin-bottom:-35px">
    <video style="margin-bottom:-150px"
poster="bgv.png" x5-playsinline="" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" x5-video-player-type="h5" x-webkit-airplay="true">
      <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>  
</template>
```

using this php

```
<?
$vids = [];
if(isset($_REQUEST["limit"], $_REQUEST["start"])) {
  $sSQL='SELECT * from posts  WHERE created_at >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 DAY order by uni';
  $result =   $db->getRecFrmQry($sSQL.' LIMIT '.$_REQUEST["start"].', '.$_REQUEST["limit"].' ');
  foreach($result as $val) {
    $vids[] = $val['video'];
  }
}  
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($vids);
?>
```

Comment: Page still freezing , I'm loading two videos per request

Comment: Can you show this on a web server somewhere?

Comment: Please see the update - I tried to make it as performant as possible.

Comment: @mpungja Source url not appending to video